# Storage Spaces Write Cache Not Disabling

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-server-2019, refs

I posted this to TechNet forums and haven't had much luck in getting an answer, so hopefully someone here can point out what I'm missing. I'm trying to create a Storage Spaces mirror-accelerated parity drive in Windows Server 2019, but I can't seem to disable the Write Buffer in RAM for it.  When I copy files to it, it spikes up the RAM usage and then flushes to disk.  I am using 2 SSDs and 3 HDDs for this pool and below are the commands I am using to create the drive.  I'd be grateful if anyone can point out the flaw.

`New-StoragePool -StoragePoolFriendlyName "MyPool" -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName (Get-StorageSubSystem).FriendlyName -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true) -FaultDomainAwarenessDefault PhysicalDisk
Set-StoragePool -FriendlyName "MyPool" -IsPowerProtected $true
Get-Storagepool MyPool | Set-ResiliencySetting -Name Mirror -NumberOfColumnsDefault 1
Get-Storagepool MyPool | Set-ResiliencySetting -Name Parity -NumberOfColumnsDefault 3
New-StorageTier -StoragePoolFriendlyName MyPool -FriendlyName SSDTier -MediaType SSD -ResiliencySettingName Mirror -NumberOfColumns 1 -PhysicalDiskRedundancy 1 -FaultDomainAwareness PhysicalDisk
New-StorageTier -StoragePoolFriendlyName MyPool -FriendlyName HDDTier -MediaType HDD -ResiliencySettingName Parity -NumberOfColumns 3 -PhysicalDiskRedundancy 1 -FaultDomainAwareness PhysicalDisk -Interleave 64KB
New-Volume -StoragePoolFriendlyName MyPool -FriendlyName MyMedia -FileSystem ReFS -WriteCacheSize 0GB -DriveLetter G -StorageTierFriendlyName SSDTier,HDDTier -StorageTierSizes 50GB,3.5TB`